# How to print Localstorage array values in tabular form using a loop?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, local-storage, angular-local-storage

i am storing form submissions in localstorage key as an array 'fsubs' like this:

```
var fsubs = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('fsubs') || "[]");
var fcodes = {"barcodeno" : this.form.value.barcode, "reelno" : this.form.value.reelno, "width" : this.form.value.width, "dia" : this.form.value.dia, "weight" : this.form.value.weight};
fsubs.push(fcodes);
localStorage.setItem('fsubs', JSON.stringify(fsubs));
```

Now the problem is that I have to print this values in a tabular form like this using a loop maybe but i dont know how to do it.

Barcode | Reelno

122121 | 232323

P.S.: I want to print this in my component using typescript in Angular

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this:

component.ts:

```
fsubList:Array<any> = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('fsubs'));
```

template:

```
<table>
   <tr>
    <th>Barcode</th>
    <th>Reelno</th>
  </tr>
  <tr *ngFor="let item of fsubList">
    <td>{{item.barcodeno}}</td>
    <td>{{item.reelno}}</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: I am getting this error
```Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: JSON.Parse is not a function```

Comment: `console.log(localStorage.getItem('fsubs'))` and show the output

Comment: yes ```Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: JSON.Parse is not a function``` it is coming in console

Comment: and use small `p` in parse. `JSON.parse`

Comment: I want the data stored in the localstorage to automatically update in the view. How do I do it?
Here the user have to refresh the page,for the data to be showed in the view

Comment: @NetranjitBorgohain You can use timeinterval to continuously check local storage value

Comment: @AdritaSharma Can you give me some example?